# Redirection stopped working after sometime on Production

Tags: spring, spring-security, redirect, sap-commerce-cloud

I am facing a very strange issue only on the Production server.

I am using **SAP Hybris** which use **Spring security**.

When the user is trying to access any secure URL of the site, it gets redirected to the login page, once he logging to the system it redirects back to the URL he was trying to access before. This is expected behavior.

Now on production storefront nodes, it's working fine for some time(Say about 30minute) when I restart the server. And then it stopped working. After login user redirects to the homepage instead of the secure URL he was trying to access.

**Note:** It's working absolutely fine in all lower environment(Local, DEV, Stage etc).

Any idea? Your help would be appreciated!!

---

**Edit:-** This issue happens even I directly access my application node(tomcat server) using IP address, So I don't think it's related to LB/cache server/web server/any cluster setting.

Comment: For all url (basket, payment, ticket, etc) or some of them?

Comment: Yes for all url

Comment: Do you have cluster system? May be login request redirected to another node. You can check Node Id in header.

Comment: Yes, but this happen even I access directly application node(tomcat)

Comment: It sounds really like you have some issues with your infrastructure. What's about the LoadBalancer and 'sticky sessions' did you check this one? Maybe you could give us an abstract about your system setup.

Comment: Yes, Initially I thought the same, I checked all possible thing. As I said in above comment. Issue is still there If I access tomcat (storefront node) directly. So I don't think issue is with the web server or LB.

Comment: If node domain different then site url, it will try to redirect it to LB domain. LB hasn't got session and may be redirect it to any one. Also cookies not send because of domain change. Another scenario: Did you check node memory usage? Maybe it can be remove some session data because of memory.

Comment: Thanks mkysoft. Yes, I had all this doubt in my mind before. But really that shouldn't be the case. Because if the session was not sticky(redirect to another node), then the user won't be login to the site, but here he is able to login to the site. Just that he redirected to the homepage and then he can access any secure URLs. Another point is I am able to regenerate this issue even I access directly Hybris application node using IP(LB won't come into the picture). Let me check memory usage.

Comment: Do you use the Secureportaladdon? If so, any difference between secured areas like the my-account area and other URLs?

Comment: Thanks all for your help and time. @andi no, it's not related to secure portal addon. But yeah I think I got the culprit code. I will post detail soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's been long time, so I forgot the exact cause of the issue. I think I was able to regenerate it in my local and fixed it by overriding forceDefaultTargetUrlBySession method of StorefrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler. Here is my committed code.

```
protected void forceDefaultTargetUrlBySession(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
{
    //if redirected from some specific url, need to remove the cachedRequest to force use defaultTargetUrl
    final RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    final SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    if (savedRequest != null)
    {
        if (savedRequest.getRedirectUrl() != null && StringUtils.contains(savedRequest.getRedirectUrl(), PASSWORD_UPDATE_PAGE_PATH))
        {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```